# NGINX : How to have sticky session with least connected

Tags: node.js, session, nginx, koa

I am using ip_hash(Sticky Session) and I have a scenario for our web portal where portal is accessible over web, and we have support module which is also hosted on the same portal, and upstream is having load balanced with 22 nodes

1. No problem for customers using portal for Sticky Session.
2. Users loging in from support center are having performance issue because sticky session is making upstream to point same node for all user's which are having same external public IP.

Need help regarding point 2. I want to distribute load for them as well, as there are concurrent 1000 user working form support center

My Config look likes

```
upstream appserver{
    ip_hash;
    server 192.168.0.x:3811;
    server 192.168.0.x:3812;
    server 192.168.0.x:3813;
    server 192.168.0.x:3814;
    server 192.168.0.x:3815;
    server 192.168.0.y:3811;
    server 192.168.0.y:3812;
    server 192.168.0.y:3813;
    server 192.168.0.y:3814;
    server 192.168.0.y:3815;
    ...
    ...
}    

server {
    location "/support" {
        allow ...;
        deny  all;
        alias ...;
        index index.html;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://appserver;
        proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure;";
        proxy_set_header   X-IBanking   "127.0.0.1";
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP    $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
        proxy_set_header   X-Request-Id $txid;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15552000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_vary on;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration here? Are both the portal and support module defined in the same upstream, or are they defined in separate upstreams? I have little knowledge about this, but seems to me if they are configured separately, the ip-hash will be separate, and they wont balance based on eachother, only themselves. While configuring under the same upstream would allow them to be evenly distributed among all servers. Alternatively you should ignore sticky sessions and set up a common redis server to handle sessions across instances

Comment: @Stian, I have updated with config. I am using same upstream and i cant ignore sessions. If you have any solution for making non sticky session with koa.js(node.js) please provide the sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its possible with nginx alone.
I'm using koa-generic-session with redis. in this way all your nodes connect to redis to read/write the session values, and the seesion follows the user to any upstream server, as long as that server is connected to your redis server.

this example is taken from https://github.com/koajs/generic-session

```
var session = require('koa-generic-session');
var redisStore = require('koa-redis');
var koa = require('koa');

var app = koa();
app.keys = ['keys', 'keykeys'];
app.use(session({
  store: redisStore()
}));

app.use(function *() {
  switch (this.path) {
  case '/get':
    get.call(this);
    break;
  case '/remove':
    remove.call(this);
    break;
  case '/regenerate':
    yield regenerate.call(this);
    break;
  }
});

function get() {
  var session = this.session;
  session.count = session.count || 0;
  session.count++;
  this.body = session.count;
}

function remove() {
  this.session = null;
  this.body = 0;
}

function *regenerate() {
  get.call(this);
  yield this.regenerateSession();
  get.call(this);
}

app.listen(8080);
```

this is what i'm currently using for sessions in a multible upstream environment.

Comment: I am using the same and able to store session id into DB but session has many other values combined with it like authorised pages, userId and other stuff which currently is on the fly into 1 instance, I need to store and share these as well

Comment: I do store more than one value in the session store... works for me without a problem...

Comment: session store means on browser session?
I need to share session data(not only session id) between multiple node instances across systems which are behind nginx reverse proxy

Comment: no, session store means you use redis to store session data on a server. every node instance must have access to the redis session store. When a user visits your site on any of your node instances, a cookie id is generated. all session data is then stored in redis under this id. the cookie id is then part of every request (as long as your session is not timed out...). If a user hits  another instance the coookie id is retrieved from the request, then the data asociated with this id is loaded from redis. This all happens in the background when you use koa-generic-session...

Comment: Can you please provide any sample code for radis with koa-generic-session

Comment: the example above already is. The code assumes redis is running on the same machine as your node instances. then this line `app.use(session({store: redisStore()}));` tells koa-generic-session to use your local redis install (default port is 6973). to use a redis install on another machine just do `redisStore({host:"111.222.333.555",port:"1234"})` see koa-redis and node-redis for deatils.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am trying out the things. If stuck somewhere will contact you.

Comment: yes, please contact me if i can assist you in any way.